# CakePHP 3 : date comparison in view

Tags: cakephp, date-comparison, cakephp-3.2

I'm working on CakePHP 3.2.

I want to compare date from `timestamp` in database with `isThisMonth()` function of CakePHP.

I am listing products whose `created` date is within `1 month`. It will show `NEW` badge with product.

This is what I have done in view

```
<?php $date = new DateTime($product->created);
      $date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
      if ($date->isThisMonth()): ?>   // error is pointing this line
         <span class="new-product"> NEW</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here `$product` is an error item and `created` is a timestamp column in database.

But this gives error as

```
Call to a member function isThisMonth() on string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this below `$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');`

```
$time = new Time($date);
```

then swap `$date->isThisMonth()):` with `$time->isThisMonth()):`

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#comparing-with-the-present

include `use Cake\I18n\Time;` in `view.ctp`.

Comment: solved.. just added `use Cake\I18n\Time;` in `view.ctp` file

Comment: you beat me to it.

Comment: This sounds overly complex. Why are you taking a DateTime object, formatting it into a string, and then converting back to an object, instead of just using the object you have in the first place?

Comment: You make a fair point, but the question explicitly says that they want to use the cake function `isThisMonth()`, so it's necessary to create a `Time` object.  I didn't look too closely, but maybe `$date = new DateTime($product->created);` could be replaced with `$time = new Time($product->created);` which would simplify things.